# sum of odious numbers to the power of k

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

In number theory, an odious number is a positive integer that has an odd number of $1$s in its binary expansion.

The first odious numbers are:

$1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 16, 19, 21, 22, 25, 26, 28, 31, 32, 35, 37, 38...$

Let $a$ denote the increasing sequence of odious numbers where $a_0=1$, $a_1=2$, etc.

Whats the summatory function of the sequence $b$ where $b_i=a_i^k$?

Also: [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262641164_Beyond_odious_and_evil) is useful; but it didn't give out the actual function. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps one can use the fact that any permutation of the binary digits of an odious number gives rise to the binary expansion of another odious number, so group theoretic considerations may be useful.

Comment: Also, defining an "inner product" on odious numbers $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ as $\sum_{i}b_{1}(i)b_{2}(i)$ where $n_{j}=\sum_{i\geq 0}b_{j}(i)2^{i}$, one can easily figure out that the sum of an odd number of pairwise orthogonal odious numbers is an odious number.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that, for $n$ large, roughly half the positive integers up to $n$ are odious, and the sum of their $k$th powers would be roughly $(1/2)\sum_{r=1}^nr^k$.

Comment: The sum $a_n$ of the first $n$ odious numbers is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A173209 and the formula $a_n=n^2-(n/2)+O(1)$, attributed to Charles R Greathouse IV, is given without proof.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is no simple formula here, although we can get some recurrence relations and related identities for generating functions as explained below.

---

Similarly to odious numbers, we have *evil numbers* that contain even number of 1s in their binary representation.

Let $S^o_k(n)$ and $S^e_k(n)$ denote the sum of $k$-th powers of all odious and evil numbers $\leq n$, respectively.

It can be easily seen that each odious number has one of the two forms: $2m$ where $m$ is an odious number, or $2m+1$ where $m$ is an evil number. It follows that for $n\geq 1$
$$S^o_k(n) = S^o_k(\lfloor\tfrac{n}2\rfloor)2^k + \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} S^e_i(\lfloor\tfrac{n-1}2\rfloor) 2^i$$
and similarly
$$S^e_k(n) = S^e_k(\lfloor\tfrac{n}2\rfloor)2^k + \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} S^o_i(\lfloor\tfrac{n-1}2\rfloor) 2^i.$$
We also have $S^o_k(0)=S^e_k(0)=0$ for all $k\geq 1$, and $S^o_0(0)=0$ and $S^e_0(0)=1$.

---

In terms of generating functions $F^o(x,y):=\sum_{n,k\geq 0} S^o_k(n) x^n \frac{y^k}{k!}$ and $F^e(x,y):=\sum_{n,k\geq 0} S^e_k(n) x^n \frac{y^k}{k!}$, we have
$$F^o(x,y) = (1+x)F^o(x^2,2y) + (x+x^2) F^e(x^2,2y) e^y,$$
$$F^e(x,y) = (1+x)F^e(x^2,2y) + (x+x^2) F^o(x^2,2y) e^y.$$
Defining $G(x,y):=F^e(x,y) - F^o(x,y)$, we have
$$G(x,y) = (1+x)(1 - x e^y)G(x^2,2y).$$
Also, it is easy to get
$$F^e(x,y) + F^o(x,y) = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-xe^y)}.$$

Since $G(x,y) =  \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-xe^y)} - 2F^o(x,y)$, we a standalong functional equation for $F^o$:
$$F^o(x,y) = (1+x)(1 - x e^y)F^o(x^2,2y) + \frac{xe^y}{(1-x)(1-x^2e^{2y})}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Too big to comment:
If we take the sequence of Gray code numbers to be $\{ g(m) \}_{m=0}^{\infty}$ then the $m$-th Odious number $Q(m)$ ($Q(0)=1,Q(1)=2...$) is the $g(m)$-th number of in the sequence of $g(2k+1), k=0,1,2,...,$

Hence, $Q(m)=g(2g(m)+1)$.

A formula for $m$-th Gray number is $$g(m)=\sum_{k=0} \sigma_i(m)2^{k-1}$$ where $\sigma_i(m)=\lfloor{\frac{|r_i(m)|}{2^k}}\rfloor$.

And, $r_i(m)=m-(\lfloor{\frac{m}{2^k}}\rfloor -(-1)^{\lfloor{\frac{m}{2^k}}\rfloor})2^k$.

Comment: Perhaps you should avoid the notation $O(m)$ as it has a totally different meaning in number theory.

Comment: @Sylvain JULIEN ,Oh, yes, I am changing it. Thank you.